# Cramer-Rao-Bound for squared parameter

Tags: probability-theory, parameter-estimation

I have a random sample $X_{i}, \ldots, X_{n} \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta,1)$. I would like to find the Cramer-Rao lower bound for the variance of unbiased estimators of $\theta^{2}$.

Here's what I have:

The Cramer-Rao bound is in general given by $\frac{1}{I(\theta)}$ where $I(\theta)$ denotes the Fisher information and $\theta$ is the parameter of interest. In my case the parameter of interest is $\theta^{2}$.

My approach is to reparameterize the log-likelihood to find the Fisher information for $\theta^{2}$. So I for the log-likelihood of my sample I have:

$$l(a, \boldsymbol{x}) = -nln(\sqrt{2\pi})-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-a^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2}$$ with $a := \theta^{2}$.

I get

$$\frac{\partial^{2} l}{\partial a^{2}} = -\frac{1}{2}a^{-\frac{3}{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$$

For the Fisher Information I get

$$I(a) = -E\left[\frac{\partial^{2} l}{\partial a^{2}} \right] = \frac{1}{2}na^{-1}$$ where I used the fact that the expectation of $x_{i}$ is given by $a^{\frac{1}{2}} (=\theta)$.

Therefore the Cramer-Rao lower bound is given by

$$CRLB = \frac{1}{I(a)} = \frac{2}{n}a = \frac{2}{n}\theta^{2}$$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No - check the formula for deriving Fisher Information again. You don't need the sum or loglikelihood to derive it. And check the formula for deriving the CRLB when working with a function of a parameter (in your case, $\theta^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using the formula for transformations of parameters I get $\frac{n}{4\theta^{2}}$ (in terms of the original parameterization) for the Fisher information. That seems to agree with my above result where I forgot a factor of 0.5 in my likelihood. Is it correct now?